# Q_DECLARE_METATYPE expects ctor, dtor, or type conversion before ; token

Tags: c++, qt

The class works fine but now I need to store it in a QVariant. Thought I only needed to add a Q_DECLARE_METATYPE as usual ([Docs](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtcore-tools-customtype-example.html)), but it won't compile with the macro added.

[image]

ValueRange.h

```
#ifndef VALUERANGE_H
#define VALUERANGE_H

template <typename T>
class ValueRange{
public:
    ValueRange() = default;
    ValueRange(const ValueRange &other) 
        : isInverted_(other.isInverted_), min_(other.min_), max_(other.max_){}
    ~ValueRange() = default;
    ValueRange(const T &min, const T &max) : min_(min), max_(max){}

    T min() const{ return min_; }
    T max() const{ return max_; }
    void invert(){ isInverted_ = true; }
    bool isInverted() const{ return isInverted_; }

    bool operator==(const ValueRange &other) const{
        return other.min()==min_ && other.max()==max_;
    }
    bool operator!=(const ValueRange &other) const{
        return other.min()!=min_ || other.max()!=max_;
    }
private:
    bool isInverted_ = false;
    T min_;
    T max_;
};
using IntRange = ValueRange<int>;
using DoubleRange = ValueRange<double>;
Q_DECLARE_METATYPE(IntRange);
Q_DECLARE_METATYPE(DoubleRange);

#endif // VALUERANGE_H
```

Comment: `;` is not needed after any `Q_DECLARE_*`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You read something like *How to start* guide only. Try to read the manual [QMetaType Class](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmetatype.html) referenced from that *How to start*.

Particularly you forgot to add required include.

```
#include <QMetaType>
```